# Is it possible to enforce SQLite datatypes?

Tags: sqlite

From my understanding, sqlite's datatype isn't associated to its column but to the data themselves: this practically means that you can insert any data to any column.

Is it possible to prohibit such a behaviour? I mean, I want sqlite to raise an error (or at least a warning) when I accidentally try to insert text to integer, for example.

Comment: Doesn’t sound like it ... https://www.sqlite.org/faq.html#q3

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can use CHECK constraints and [typeof()](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html#typeof) to check the actual data type:

```
CREATE TABLE MyTable (
    Col1 INTEGER  CHECK (typeof(Col1) = 'integer'),
    Col2 TEXT     CHECK (typeof(Col2) IN ('text', 'null')
);
```

Answer (score 6):

I believe you could use a `CHECK` constraint e.g.

```
CREATE TABLE testinsert (
    COL1 INTEGER, 
    COL2 INTEGER CHECK (CAST(COL2||1 AS INTEGER) <> 0) -- column constraint
    CHECK (CAST(COL1||1 AS INTEGER) <> 0) -- table constraint
);
```

- this creates a table with two columns COL1 and COL2.
- both  columns have the same constraint but applied to the columns differently

  - COL1 has the CHECK constraint applied as table-constraint
  - COL2 has the CHECK constraint applied as a column-constraint
- The constraint works by checking the value of the column when CAST to an INTEGER. The result will be 0 (false) if the value is not an INTEGER. However, to cater for 0 as a valid value 1 is concatenated to the column's value. Thus 0 will result in 1.

You could also use the **`TYPEOF`** function e.g.

```
COL3 INTEGER CHECK(typeof(COL3) = 'INTEGER')
```

- Noting that there is a subtle difference between using CAST and TYPEOF. The previous examples, using CAST, will allow integers provided as strings, whilst using the **typeof** function will only allow integers.

The following are some example INSERTS with the result :-

```
INSERT INTO testinsert VALUES(100,100); -- OK
INSERT INTO testinsert VALUES('100',100); -- OK
INSERT INTO testinsert VALUES('100','abc'); -- ouch for COL2 (abc)
INSERT INTO testinsert VALUES(0,100); -- OK
INSERT INTO testinsert VALUES('0',100); -- OK
INSERT INTO testinsert VALUES('abc',100); -- ouch  for COL1 (abc)
```

With the COL3 added to the table :-

```
INSERT INTO testinsert VALUES(100,100,100); -- OK (all integers)
INSERT INTO testinsert VALUES('100','100',100); -- OK (CAST can accept integers as strings)
INSERT INTO testinsert VALUES('100','100','100'); -- Ouch typeof will consider '100' as a string, not an integer
```

If you wanted to ignore rather than abort (the default) then you could use :-

```
INSERT OR IGNORE INTO testinsert VALUES('100','abc'); -- insert Skipped - no fail
```

---

SQLite Manager was used for testing the above.

Here's an example of the CONFLICT failure :-

> ```
> SQLiteManager:  -- OK
> INSERT INTO testinsert VALUES('100','abc'); [ CHECK constraint failed: testinsert ]
> Exception Name: NS_ERROR_STORAGE_CONSTRAINT
> Exception Message: Component returned failure code: 0x80630003 (NS_ERROR_STORAGE_CONSTRAINT) [mozIStorageStatement.execute]
> ```

You may wish to have a look at :-

- [CREATE TABLE](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtable.html)
- [table-constraint](https://www.sqlite.org/syntax/table-constraint.html)
- [column-constraint](https://www.sqlite.org/syntax/column-constraint.html)
- [ON CONFLICT clause](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_conflict.html)
- [expression - CAST expressions (near the bottom)](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html)
- [typeof(X)](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html#typeof)

Answer (score 3):

Since version 3.37.0 of SQLite it is possible to force data type checking with [STRICT Tables](https://sqlite.org/stricttables.html):

> In a CREATE TABLE statement, if the "STRICT" table-option keyword is
> added to the end, after the closing ")", then strict typing rules
> apply to that table.

You can use one of the following data types for the column definitions:

- INT
- INTEGER
- REAL
- TEXT
- BLOB
- ANY

See a simplified [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/E4KEwv1e).