# Enabling type checking in SQLite

Tags: sqlite

SQLite more or less ignores the types you give to columns. Instead individual values are dynamically typed. From the FAQ:

> **SQLite lets me insert a string into a database column of type integer!**
>
> This is a feature, not a bug. ... It does not enforce data type constraints. Data of any type can (usually) be inserted into any column.

This "feature" is pretty awful if you want to avoid bugs. Does SQLite have any options to fix this deficiency - i.e. to enforce column types?

The only thing I found was a [7 year old `strict=ON` suggestion](https://www3.sqlite.org/cgi/src/wiki?name=StrictMode) that doesn't mention types.

Comment: You may want to try this... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49230311/is-it-possible-to-force-datatype

Comment: It assumes the person or program inserting data knows what they're doing when it comes to the types being used.

Comment: A poor assumption.